# Is it possible to update bunch of different Tables in DB with the same modification to all?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to duplicate all my tables in SQL Server, all table names would have had "temp" added at the beginning. And all of them would have had added an extra column (the same to all). I don't need whole code, just general idea how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A straightforward way to go:

1. You need to fetch the table names from your database (probably using INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES).
2. For each of those tables from step 1, you need to generate a corresponding SELECT ... INTO statement.
3. You need to execute each generated SQL statement from step 2.

You already have a solution with a cursor. This is one without a cursor:

```
DECLARE @script VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @script = @script + 'SELECT * INTO [temp'+ TABLE_NAME +'] FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
EXEC (@script);
```

Remark: The CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) is not necessary; just added for readability if you want to check the script first (using PRINT instead EXEC).

Edit:

An additional question in the comments to add a checksum value in the resulting tables could be done as follows:

```
DECLARE @script VARCHAR(MAX) = '';
SELECT @script = @script + 'SELECT CHECKSUM(*) AS [__checksum], * INTO [temp'+ TABLE_NAME +'] FROM [' + TABLE_NAME + '];' + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
EXEC (@script);
```

Using HASHBYTES instead of CHECKSUM is probably better, but it accepts only two parameters: the hash algorithm and a single value to hash. So in that case, you probably need to pass a string value by manually concatenating all the fields of your tables, and that may be somewhat troublesome to add in a dynamic query like mine. It would probably result in something more complex than just three lines...

Well, something like this, actually:

```
DECLARE @script NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

WITH
    [Columns] AS
    (
        SELECT
            TABLE_NAME AS [TableName],
            COLUMN_NAME AS [ColumnName],
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION) AS [ColSeq]
        FROM
            INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    ),
    [Tables] AS
    (
        SELECT
            [TableName],
            CAST(N'[' + [ColumnName] + N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS [ColumnList],
            [ColSeq]
        FROM
            [Columns] AS C
        WHERE
            [ColSeq] = (SELECT MAX([ColSeq])
                        FROM [Columns]
                        WHERE [TableName] = C.[TableName]) 

    UNION ALL
        SELECT T.[TableName], N'[' + C.[ColumnName] + N'], ' + T.[ColumnList], C.[ColSeq]
        FROM
            [Tables] AS T
            INNER JOIN [Columns] AS C ON C.[TableName] = T.[TableName] AND C.[ColSeq] = T.[ColSeq] - 1
    )
SELECT @script = @script + N'SELECT HASHBYTES(''md5'', CONCAT(N'''', ' + [ColumnList] + N')) AS [__checksum], * INTO [temp' + [TableName] + N'] FROM [' + [TableName] + N'];' + NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10)
FROM [Tables]
WHERE [ColSeq] = 1;

EXEC (@script);
```

Remarks:

- In the recursive CTE `[Tables]`, which is used for concatenating the column names of each table in a comma-separated string value, I started at the last column and moved backwards to ease the filter condition in my main query.
- I added an additional first parameter `N''` to the `CONCAT` calls in the resulting `@script` contents, since the `CONCAT` function requires at least 2 arguments, which would be troublesome in this case when processing tables with just one column.

In this case, despite the somewhat worse performance, it might be clearer and easier to fall back to using a cursor, like @HasanMahmood suggested in his answer...

Comment: Could you tell me what the first line does? why VARCHAR(MAX)= ' ';? And how to add a checksum column to all tables in schema?

Comment: By default, the `@script` variable will be initialized to NULL. I don't want that, because then the additions performed in the second line for every result found in `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES` will result in NULL. (See CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL setting in MSDN documentation.) So I initialize the variable to an empty string first.

Comment: It's the same as `DECLARE @script VARCHAR(MAX); SET @script = '';`

Comment: A checksum is a different story... You can look into the HASHBYTES function in SQL Server, but you need to specify exactly of what (and how) you want to calculate your checksum. Perhaps that requires a StackOverflow question on its own.

Comment: Basically if I know from which columns I want to make a checksum can I do it in similar way with alter table add column?

Comment: Yes you can. You also could include a "placeholder" column in the above script, so that you only need to update it with the real checksum value. I will add a suggestion for that in my answer. Edit: adding a placeholder for later update does not seem to be necessary. You could include the actual checksum in your results immediately.

Answer (score 1):

try this code:

get all the table name form information schema and run a dynamic sql to create tables

```
DECLARE @script varchar(max)

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT script = 'Select * Into  [temp'+ TABLE_NAME +'] From ' + QUOTENAME(TABLE_NAME) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES


OPEN db_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @script  

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN  

      EXEC(@script)
      --PRINT @script

      FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @script
END 

CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
```

Comment: That's a concrete solution indeed. For safety, I would delimit table names with '[' and ']'. But personally, I would go for a solution without a cursor.

Comment: @BartHofland i have added quote, thanks. but since it is a one time task Cursor might not be an issue.

Comment: True. But in this simple case, the solution without a cursor is even simpler. Check my answer. ;)

Comment: @BartHofland, I saw your answer, But in my thought sometime in this kind of scenarios cursor might help if each table wise condition. If you want to do something based on a specific table it will help. Thanks